# StructureMap and scanning assemblies

Tags: assemblies, registry, structuremap

So, I have a .NET solution that uses StructureMap, and I'd like to have StructureMap read an outside assembly that implements an interface from a project in that solution and defines the registry entry for it.

StructreMap configuration for my solution:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(registry =>
{
  registry.Scan(assembly =>
   {
     assembly.TheCallingAssembly();

     //Telling StructureMap to sweep a folder called "extensions" directly
     //underneath the application root folder for any assemblies found in that folder
     assembly.AssembliesFromPath("extensions", addedAssembly => addedAssembly.GetName().Name.ToLower().Contains("extension"));

     //Direct StructureMap to add any Registries that it finds in these assemblies, assuming that all the StructureMap directives are
     //contained in registry classes
     assembly.LookForRegistries();
   });
});
```

Pretty straightforward, I tell it to add the calling assembly and the assembly from a directory to the assemblies collection.  I've debugged the assemblies variable and it has indeed found all the assemblies (including the one from the extensions directory).

In a DLL project I've created separate from my original solution, I have an implementation of an interface (I've referenced the interfaces project from my original solution), and written a very simple registry:

```
public class ProductMockRegistry : Registry
{
    public ProductMockRegistry()
    {
        ForRequestedType<IProductRepository>().AddInstances(repository =>
        {
            repository.OfConcreteType<ProductMockRepository>();
        });
    }
}
```

The problem I have is, StructureMap does not find the registry in the external DLL.  It finds the DLL just fine, but when I tell it to LookForRegistries, it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IoC, Dll References, and Assembly Scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809051/ioc-dll-references-and-assembly-scanning/816376#816376)