# IoC, Dll References, and Assembly Scanning

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap

Although this question is related to StructureMap, my *general* question is:

> When wiring up components with an IoC
>   container **in code** (as opposed
>   to configuring via **xml**) do you
>   generally need explicit project/build
>   references to all assemblies?

Why the separate assemblies? Because:

---

> "Abstract classes residing in a
>   separate assembly from their concrete
>   implementations are a great way to
>   achieve such separation." -**Framework
>   Design Guidelines p.91**

---

Example:

Let's say I have *PersonBase.dll* and *Bob.dll*

*Bob* inherits from the abstract class *PersonBase*. They're both in the *Person* namespace. **But in different assemblies**.

I'm programming to *PersonBase*, not *Bob*.

Back in my main code, I need a person. StructureMap can scan assemblies. Great, I'll ask StructureMap for one!

Now, in my main code, I am of course referring only to *PersonBase*, not to *Bob*. I actually don't want my code to know *anything* about *Bob*. No project references, no nuthin. That's the whole point.

So I want to say:

```
//Reference: PersonBase.dll (only)
using Person;  
...

//this is as much as we'll ever be specific about Bob:
Scan( x=> { x.Assembly("Bob.dll"); }

//Ok, I should now have something that's a PersonBase (Bob). But no ?
ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<PersonBase>().Count == 0
```

No luck. What does work is being explicit that I want Bob:

```
//Reference: PersonBase.dll and Bob.dll
using Person; 
...
Scan( x => {x.Assembly("Bob.dll"); }

//If I'm explicit, it works. But Bob's just a PersonBase, what gives?
ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<Bob>().Count == 1 //there he is!
```

But now I've had to reference *Bob.dll* in my project which is exactly what I didn't want.

I can avoid this situation using Spring + Xml configuration. But then I'm back to Spring + Xml configuration ... !

> Am I missing something with using
>   StructureMap, or as a general
>   principle, do (fluent) IoC
>   configurations need explict references
>   to all assemblies?

Possibly related question: [[StructureMap and scanning assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508399/structuremap-and-scanning-assemblies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508399/structuremap-and-scanning-assemblies)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally got this sorted out. It looks like this:

[IoC Uml http://img396.imageshack.us/img396/1343/iocuml.jpg](http://img396.imageshack.us/img396/1343/iocuml.jpg)

with the assemblies

- Core.exe

  PersonBase.dll (referenced **compile time** by Core.exe)

  Bob.dll        (**loaded up run time** via StructureMap Scan)

  Betty.dll      (**loaded up run time** via StructureMap Scan)

To get it with StructureMap, I needed a custom "ITypeScanner" to support scanning for assemblies:

```
public class MyScanner : ITypeScanner {
  public void Process(Type type, PluginGraph graph) {

    if(type.BaseType == null) return;

    if(type.BaseType.Equals(typeof(PersonBase))) {
      graph.Configure(x => 
        x.ForRequestedType<PersonBase>()
        .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType(type));
    }
  }
}
```

So my main code looks like:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.Scan (
  scan =>
  {
    scan.AssembliesFromPath(Environment.CurrentDirectory 
    /*, filter=>filter.You.Could.Filter.Here*/);

    //scan.WithDefaultConventions(); //doesn't do it

    scan.With<MyScanner>();
  }
));

ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<PersonBase>()
 .ToList()
  .ForEach(p => 
  { Console.WriteLine(p.FirstName); } );
```

Comment: You do not need to create your own scanner. In your Scan expression, use AddAllTypesOf for PersonBase. http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ScanningAssemblies.htm#section5

Answer (score 1):

You can do xml configuration with StructureMap as well.  You can even mix them if you want.

There are also StructureMap Attributes you could put in your Bob class to tell StructureMap how to load the assembly.  DefaultConstructor is one I end up using from time to time.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris :) 
If I have to go back to Xml wiring, I'll stick with Spring. I think what I have above is structurally/conceptually sound. My problem is that it seems like Ioc-configured-in-code consistently requires dll references I specifically want to avoid.

Comment: No problem.  There is nothing wrong with spring.net either.  But do be careful that you don't over-architect yourself as well.  The more projects you introduce to a solution the longer your build will take.  The more configurable you make something, more more test surface you create.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic scan option only works when you keep the naming, assembly and namespace conventions. You can manually configure structuremap with a fluent interface. Example:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(initialization => 
   initialization.ForRequestedType<PersonBase>()
    .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<Bob>());
```

Comment: In this case -- which is basically my 2nd scenario that works but involves the dll reference -- I need the dll reference to Bob.dll. Which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: [...] .Is.OfConcreteType<Bob>() //<-- you need a dll reference to Bob.dll for that

Comment: I understand what you mean, but it's still impossible to set up an IoC container without dependencies on the types you want to configure.

Comment: got this sorted out-- see answer below

Answer (score 0):

What we do on my current project (which uses AutoFac, not StructureMap, but I think it shouldn't make a difference):

We have the interfaces defining external services that the application uses in a core assembly, let's say `App.Core` (like your PersonBase).

Then we have the implementations of these interfaces in `Services.Real` (like Bob.dll).

In our case we also have `Service.Fake`, which are used for facilitating UI testing with dependencies on other enterprise services and databases, etc.

The front-end "client" application itself (in our case, ASP.NET MVC app) references `App.Core`.

When the app starts, we use `Assembly.Load` to load the appropriate "Services" implementation DLL, based on a config setting.

Each of these DLLs has an implementation of IServiceRegistry that returns a list of the services that it implements:

```
public enum LifestyleType { Singleton, Transient, PerRequest}

public class ServiceInfo {
    public Type InterfaceType {get;set;}
    public Type ImplementationType {get;set;}
    // this might or might not be useful for your app, 
    // depending on the types of services, etc.
    public LifestyleType Lifestyle {get;set;} 
}

public interface IServiceRegistry {
    IEnumerable<ServiceInfo> GetServices();
}
```

... the application finds this ServiceRegistry via reflection and enumerates through these ServiceInfo instances and registers them on the container. For us, this register-all-services lives in the Web application, but it's possible (and preferable in many cases) to have it in a separate assembly.

This way we can isolate the domain logic from the infrastructure code, and prevent "just-this-once" work-arounds where the application ends up depending on a direct reference to the infrastructure code. We also avoid having to have a reference to the container in each Services implementation.

One really important thing if you are doing this: make *sure* that you have tests that verify that you can create each "top-level" type (in our case, ASP.NET MVC Controllers) with each potential configuration of the IOC container.

Otherwise, it is pretty easy to forget to implement one interface and break huge sections of your application.